# How to set a FCM based alarm using firebase cloud functions?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on Firebase FireStore and Firebase real time database apps, 
how can I set an alarm (based on a value set by the user) on android using firebase cloud functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no one-time scheduling functionality in Cloud Functions.  You will have to provide your own scheduling mechanism, and that could trigger an HTTP function that deals with Firestore or Realtime Database.

Comment: Thanks Doug Stevenson, I hope Firebase team will remove this barrier in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javacript native function in Firebasefunctions -

> setTimeOut()
>
> setInterval()

for triggering some events .

Working for me.My use case is to trigger some API after each 5mins.

Sample Code -

```
    exports.process_sms = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      admin.database().ref(FIREBASE_DB + '/sms_new').once('value').then(function(users) {
    let sms_array = [];
    users.forEach(function(user) {
      user.forEach(function(sms) {
        if (sms.val().status == 0) {
          sms_array.push(sms);
        }
      });
    });
    let i = 0;
    let interval = setInterval(function() {
    // do your work ... and it gets repeated after 2 sec
    }, 2000);
    res.status(200).send("Sms processing Done");
});
});
```

Comment: can you write code here?, so that i can see what i can do with my code.